# Is MQTT subcribe idempotent for non clean connection

Tags: mqtt

I have an MQTT client which is subscribed to multiple topics. I set `clean session` `false` and `QoS` `1` so when I'm offline messages will be enqueued.

But each time I come online, I subscribe same topics with same flags in init function. Would it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each time I come online, I subscribe same topics with same flags in init function. Would it cause any problems?

The [MQTT (3.1.1) spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800440) states:

> If a Server receives a SUBSCRIBE Packet containing a Topic Filter that is identical to an existing Subscription’s Topic Filter then it MUST completely replace that existing Subscription with a new Subscription. The Topic Filter in the new Subscription will be identical to that in the previous Subscription, although its maximum QoS value could be different. Any existing retained messages matching the Topic Filter MUST be re-sent, but the flow of publications MUST NOT be interrupted [MQTT-3.8.4-3].

The situation with [MQTT V5](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc384800440) is similar:

> If a Server receives a SUBSCRIBE packet containing a Topic Filter that is identical to a Non‑shared Subscription’s Topic Filter for the current Session, then it MUST replace that existing Subscription with a new Subscription [MQTT-3.8.4-3]. The Topic Filter in the new Subscription will be identical to that in the previous Subscription, although its Subscription Options could be different. If the Retain Handling option is 0, any existing retained messages matching the Topic Filter MUST be re-sent, but Applicaton Messages MUST NOT be lost due to replacing the Subscription [MQTT-3.8.4-4].

So subscribing to a topic the client is already subscribed to (with the same QOS etc) should not cause any issues (you may receive retained messages) and is a common pattern (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65122380/11810946) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51793695/11810946)).